# Two lists, one of words, one of phrases

Tags: python, regex, filter

Ok, so I have two lists, one of words, like so:

```
["happy", "sad", "angry", "jumpy"]
```

etc

And then a list of phrases, like so:

```
["I'm so happy with myself lately!", "Johnny, im so sad, so very sad, call me", "i feel like crap. SO ANGRY!!!!"]
```

I want to use the first list of words, to find the incidences of words in the list of phrases. I don't care if I pull the actual words, separated by spaces or just the number of times they occur.

From what I've looked into, it appears that the re module as well as filters are the way to go?

Also, if my explanation of what I need is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: This is a bit more clear than your other question.

Comment: You don't need re or filters. The built in operators 'in' and str.'count' will do the job as efficiently (in that order). The solutions below by katrielalex and poke demonstrate both approaches. Ofcourse, re can also do the job for you but would be using a canon where a knife would do :-)

Comment: @GeneralBecos: He might need a regex to split each phrase into words. If not `"an" in "I might be American"` would return true, even though the word "an" is not in that phrase.

Comment: Yea, I'm determining if I need a regex. And yes, this is a lot better of an explanation. I realized that I wasn't being clear enough in my questions. Whenever I try to simplify questions, I find that there's misunderstanding, so I should just straight out say what I need, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> phrases = ["I'm so happy with myself lately!", "Johnny, im so sad, so very sad, call me", "i feel like crap. SO ANGRY!!!!"]
>>> words = ["happy", "sad", "angry", "jumpy"]
>>> 
>>> for phrase in phrases:
...     print phrase
...     print {word: phrase.count(word) for word in words}
... 
I'm so happy with myself lately!
{'jumpy': 0, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 0, 'happy': 1}
Johnny, im so sad, so very sad, call me
{'jumpy': 0, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 2, 'happy': 0}
i feel like crap. SO ANGRY!!!!
{'jumpy': 0, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 0, 'happy': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, straight-forward solution:

```
>>> phrases = ["I'm so happy with myself lately!", "Johnny, im so sad, so very sad, call me", "i feel like crap. SO ANGRY!!!!"]
>>> words = ["happy", "sad", "angry", "jumpy"]
>>> for phrase in phrases:
        for word in words:
            if word in phrase:
                print('"{0}" is in the phrase "{1}".'.format(word, phrase))

"happy" is in the phrase "I'm so happy with myself lately!".
"sad" is in the phrase "Johnny, im so sad, so very sad, call me".
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to count instances. So in the Johnny status, I'd need to record more than one. Also, I could plug in a regular expression for this as well, right?

Comment: You can easily change the print to whatever you want to do with a match. According to your question you “don't care” what to do with them, so you should be more specific next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> phrases = ["I'm so happy with myself lately!", "Johnny, im so sad, so very sad, call me", "i feel like crap. SO ANGRY!!!!"]
>>> words = ["happy", "sad", "angry", "jumpy"]
>>> words_in_phrases = [re.findall(r"\b[\w']+\b", phrase.lower()) for phrase in phrases]
>>> words_in_phrases
[["i'm", 'so', 'happy', 'with', 'myself', 'lately'], ['johnny', 'im', 'so', 'sad', 'so', 'very', 'sad', 'call', 'me'], ['i', 'feel', 'like', 'crap', 'so', 'angry']]
>>> word_counts = [{word: phrase.count(word) for word in words} for phrase in words_in_phrases]
>>> word_counts
[{'jumpy': 0, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 0, 'happy': 1}, {'jumpy': 0, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 2, 'happy': 0}, {'jumpy': 0, 'angry': 1, 'sad': 0, 'happy': 0}]
>>>
```

For the line `word_counts = [{word: phrase.count(word) for word in words} for...`, you need Python 2.7+. If, for some reason, you're using < Python 2.7, replace that line with the following:

```
>>> word_counts = [dict((word, phrase.count(word)) for word in words) for phrase in words_in_phrases]
```